# $g'(x)d(x) = d(g(x))$, is this true? Why?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have encountered this after having studied the substitution rule for integrals where:

if $ f(x) = h(g(x))g'(x)$ then $$ \int f(x) \, dx = \int h(g(x)) \, d(g(x))) $$

Assuming $ d() $  is in fact a "differentiator operator", then can you apply the operator both sides of a given equation? For example:

$$ x^2 = y$$
$$ d(x^2) = d(y)$$
$$ 2xdx = dy$$
$$ 2x = \frac{dy}{dx} $$

and apply the $d()$ operator again:

$$ d(2x) = d(\frac{dy}{dx})) $$
$$ 2dx = d(\frac{dy}{dx})) $$
$$ 2dx = \frac{d^2y}{dx}$$
$$ 2 = \frac{d^2y}{dx}* \frac{1}{dx} $$
$$ 2 = \frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2}$$

Is this valid notation wise?

Comment: do you know chain rule of diffrentiation

Comment: At first I thought you were asking whether your valid notation was wise! I think a judicious hyphen would solve that.